# What's the meaning of "dummy up"?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does "dummy up" mean here?

> The cops wouldn't tell me who the owner was, but we're a military town, so I took a chance. Called my insurance (USAA) and as luck would have it, that was the other guy's insurance too!...Got my mechanic to **dummy up** a $50 statement, just to submit it to USAA and have it on the douche's record. That's what he gets for being a lying asshole.

Comment: by itself I would have figured 'to dummy up' meant 'to shut up': 'Why don't you dummy up' = ' Shut up' = (rudely) 'Be quiet'. But the usage here seems to be 'make a dummy' = 'make up a false copy'. That is using 'dummy' as a known for a fake, then verbing it as a common phrasal verb pattern with 'up'.

Comment: We do this all the time.  You make up some placeholder text and/or graphics prior to a final just as something to work with.  Dummy up some copy, dummy up a flyer, dummy up a one page report, etc.

Comment: Voting general reference, since 'dummy' in verb context is readily available in dictionaries.

Comment: In case it helps, I believe that “douche” is some sort of U.S. getto and/or little children’s slang meaning “dummy”, “dolt”, “jerk”, or “idiot”. In other words, a meaningless pejorative for someone we don’t like. Compare U.K. “wanker”.

Comment: @Mitch: As you say, this can not be easily and clearly resolved by consulting a dictionary, so it isn't a General Reference, is it?

Comment: @tchrist  *Douche* here is a shortened form of *douchebag*, a term of opprobrium used throughout the under-25 US speech community. It implies that the nominee is not merely an asshole but insufferably smug and self-satisfied to boot.

Comment: @Mitch: I see you've got a couple of upvotes for commenting *dummy up = shut up*, which I've never heard before (though I've certainly heard and said *"Shut up, dummy!"* countless times). And by implication from your *"here it **seems** to be"*, you're not familiar with *to dummy up an xxx* meaning *create a not-quite-authentic xxx*. Is there perhaps a US/UK difference involved here?

Comment: @Cerberus: I wouldn't have thought it is GR. But maybe Green's Dictionary of Slang is considered such a source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, I was not familiar with 'to dummy up' as to make a fake copy. And 'dummy up' as 'to make oneself quiet' is familiar. As an AmE speaker and you speaking BrE, with a pair size of 1, there is some evidence that it is a UK/US difference. Is Green a UK author?

Comment: @Mitch: [Jonathon Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathon_Green) *has even been described as 'The most-acclaimed British lexicographer since Johnson'.*

Comment: @Mitch: I have never heard of this dictionary...am I too dumb for GR?

Comment: @Cerberus: Me neither. Look at Brian Hooper's answer below.

Comment: @Cerberus: If even *you* are too dumb, perhaps we'd better just close the site itself down as *Too Localised!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Gracias! Meanwhile, I will try to dumby up. Or down. I don't know.

Comment: @Cerberus: Don't beat yourself up! I only quoted that line from Wikipedia as a wind-up to Mitch (I'd never heard of Green before I Googled his *Dictionary of Slang* then). I've heard of [Cassell's](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Cassell_Dict_Slang.html?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&redir_esc=y) because they're a big (and British) publishing house. And [Partridge's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dictionary-Slang-Unconventional-English-Unconvetional/dp/0415291895) because when I was a schoolboy we used to look up dirty words in his slang dictionary. That's the limit of my academic credentials!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means to create a fake or (more commonly in computer engineering) a placeholder for an actual object.

Answer (score 7):

According to Green's *Dictionary of Slang*, *dummy up* has several meanings:-

> **dummy (up)** v. (SE *dummy*, a sham) (US) to concoct a fraud, to fake something up

Alternatively

> **dummy up** v.
>
> 1. to pose as a mute
> 2. to stop talking
> 3. to keep quiet, to keep secret

In the example you cite it looks like the the first (fraud, fake) meaning is intended.

Comment: Because I've never come across any of that second set of definitions before, I just searched Google Books for ["can dummy up"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22can+dummy+up%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which seemed like a reasonable sequence to be used in either sense. Of 29 results, at least 20 were obviously for the "fake up" meaning, and I could only see one (cop talking to taciturn suspect) for the "silence" meaning. Are you citing it because you *know and use* it, or just because it was given in Green's?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I may have used it to mean "keep quiet, keep secret" in my schoolboy days (when one has to do that sort of thing) but I can't remember. Certainly not for any of the other meanings.